# How to add data dynamically do Google Timeline chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Actually i'm trying to make a restaurant booking system using Google Timeline Chart.

I was just trying the function of the Timeline and onClick i would to add new data to the Chart with the values from the form.

Subsequently the data will be saved in the database and even load from it on page load but.

[image]

Here is javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["timeline"] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Tavolo' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addRows([
            ['Tavolo 1', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 00, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 00, 0)],
            ['Tavolo 2', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 00, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 00, 0)],
            ['Tavolo 3', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0)],
            ['Tavolo 3', new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0)],
            ['Tavolo 3', new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0)],
            ['Tavolo 4', new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0)],
            ['Tavolo 4', new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0)],
            ['Tavolo 5', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 13, 30, 0)],
            ['Tavolo 6', new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 30, 0)],
            ['Tavolo 7', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0)],
            ['Tavolo 8', new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0)],
            ['Tavolo 8', new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0)],
            ['Tavolo 9', new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0)]]);


        var options = {
            timeline: { singleColor: '#ff0000' }
        };

        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
        // Function to remove 0 value bars
        (function () {                                            
            var el = container.getElementsByTagName("rect");     
            var width = 100000000;                            
            var elToRem = [];                                     
            for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {                           
                var cwidth = parseInt(el[i].getAttribute("width"));
                if (cwidth < width) {                          
                    elToRem = [el[i]];
                    width = cwidth;                               
                }
                else if (cwidth == width) {                         
                    elToRem.push(el[i]);
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < elToRem.length; i++) 
                elToRem[i].setAttribute("fill", "none"); 
        })();
    }

    function addPrenotazione() {
        dataTable.addRows(["Tavolo" + $("#tavolo").val(), new Date($("#datainizio").val()), new Date($("#datafine").val())]);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the chart must be re-drawn anytime new data is added or options change.

```
    function addPrenotazione() {
        dataTable.addRows(["Tavolo" + $("#tavolo").val(), new Date($("#datainizio").val()), new Date($("#datafine").val())]);
        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    }
```

move the above function inside the `drawChart` function,
this will allow the function access to the `dataTable` and `chart` variables...

also don't recommend using inline event handlers on elements...

```
onclick="addPrenotazione"
```

instead, add the event inside the `drawChart` function as well...

```
document.getElementById('prenota').addEventListener('click', addPrenotazione);  // 'prenota' or whatever the button id is...
```

finally, when modifying chart elements, wait for the `'ready'`,
to ensure the chart has finished drawing...

```
    // Function to remove 0 value bars
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        var el = container.getElementsByTagName("rect");
        var width = 100000000;
        var elToRem = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            var cwidth = parseInt(el[i].getAttribute("width"));
            if (cwidth < width) {
                elToRem = [el[i]];
                width = cwidth;
            }
            else if (cwidth == width) {
                elToRem.push(el[i]);
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < elToRem.length; i++)
            elToRem[i].setAttribute("fill", "none");
    });
```

recommend setup similar to following...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['timeline']
}).then(function () {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Tavolo' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Tavolo 1', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 00, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 00, 0)],
    ['Tavolo 2', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 00, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 00, 0)],
    ['Tavolo 3', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0)],
    ['Tavolo 3', new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0)],
    ['Tavolo 3', new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0)],
    ['Tavolo 4', new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0)],
    ['Tavolo 4', new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0)],
    ['Tavolo 5', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 13, 30, 0)],
    ['Tavolo 6', new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 30, 0)],
    ['Tavolo 7', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0)],
    ['Tavolo 8', new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0)],
    ['Tavolo 8', new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0)],
    ['Tavolo 9', new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 30, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0)]
  ]);

  var options = {
    timeline: { singleColor: '#ff0000' }
  };

  chart.draw(dataTable, options);

  // Function to remove 0 value bars
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var el = container.getElementsByTagName("rect");
    var width = 100000000;
    var elToRem = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      var cwidth = parseInt(el[i].getAttribute("width"));
      if (cwidth < width) {
        elToRem = [el[i]];
        width = cwidth;
      }
      else if (cwidth == width) {
        elToRem.push(el[i]);
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < elToRem.length; i++)
      elToRem[i].setAttribute("fill", "none");
  });

  document.getElementById('prenota').addEventListener('click', addPrenotazione);

  function addPrenotazione() {
    dataTable.addRows(["Tavolo" + $("#tavolo").val(), new Date($("#datainizio").val()), new Date($("#datafine").val())]);
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
});
```

you'll need to make the dates match the format of the original data,
with zero used for the year.

```
function addPrenotazione() {
  var dateBeg = new Date($("#datainizio").val());
  var dateEnd = new Date($("#datafine").val());
  dataTable.addRow(["Tavolo" + $("#tavolo").val(), new Date(0, 0, 0, dateBeg.getHours(), dateBeg.getMinutes(), dateBeg.getSeconds()), new Date(0, 0, 0, dateEnd.getHours(), dateEnd.getMinutes(), dateEnd.getSeconds())]);
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

Comment: That's adding the value to the chart but the issue is that the insert data is incorrect the chart become unreadable, is it the right way to get date value from datatime-local with new Date($("#datainizio").val())?

Comment: is a             <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="datainizio" />

Comment: check the screenshot, Arrivo is label of datainizio and it's value is 19/03/2019 12:00

Comment: Tue Mar 19 2019 12:21:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale) that's the output of new Date($("datainizio").val()) if i put it in an alert

Comment: that looks fine, however, the original dates were added with zero for the year, so the dates are too far apart.

Comment: actually i've changed all the values to today's date but having still same problem

Comment: changed answer above, also need to use `addRow` instead of `addRows`

Comment: that's working fine but i was trying to add the dateBeg.getFullYear() month and day instead of 0 and i had the same unreadable chart, the initial rows value was changed to new Date(2019, 03, 19) as date

Comment: in that case, you should be able to go back to `new Date($("#datainizio").val())`